# passing two objects in eval() - Groovy (soapUI assertion using variables)

Tags: groovy, eval

I've a statement like this

```
eval.me ('a' , a , "assert something == something: log.info("some info")")
```

where a is

```
a = Jsonslurper.parseText(someContent)
```

eval statement works when assert is true but doest not give me `log.info` when assert is false. I figured out that I need to pass `log` object to eval. `log`  object is directly avaialable in my script. So I was trying this

```
eval.xy(a,log, "assert something == something: log.info("some info")")
```

but gives me error that `no such property a` . Whats wrong and how can I correct that. Thanks!

**EDIT:** Actual call is :

```
Eval.me('RespJson', RespJson, "assert ${RespNode}.toString() == '$aValue': log.info(\"${context.expand( '${#Project#assertValue}' )}\")")
```

which gives me `No such property:  log` and hence I was trying the call that I mention in my original post

Comment: Can you paste your actual eval call? The problem is that you are referring to `a`, but that form of eval passes them in as `x` and `y`. However, I suspect you have edited your actual failing code and in doing so have removed the bit of greatest importance

Comment: @tim_yates Thank you for your response. I edited my question to include original call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Eval.xy()` binds the first two parameters to variables named `x` and `y` respectively. There is no way to bind your parameters to specific names of your choice, as there is with `Eval.me()`. Thus, if you are determined to use `Eval.xy()` you must change the script accordingly:

```
Eval.xy(RespJson, log, "assert ${RespNode}.toString() == '$aValue': y.info(\"${context.expand( '${#Project#assertValue}' )}\")")
```

Furthermore, if your local variable `RespNode` expands into a string expression involving `RespJson` (as I suspect it does), then you will have to replace every occurrence of `RespJson` with `x`.

A more flexible approach would be to use `GroovyShell` and `Binding` in place of `Eval`, like this:

```
def binding = new Binding(RespJson: RespJson, log: log)
new GroovyShell(binding).evaluate("assert ${RespNode}.toString() == '$aValue': log.info(\"${context.expand( '${#Project#assertValue}' )}\")")
```

Comment: thank you . I tried to use this as suggested `Eval.xy(RespJson, log, "assert ${RespNode}.toString() == '$aValue': y.info(\"${context.expand( '${#Project#assertValue}' )}\")")` but I am still getting `no such property : log`.And I am assuming that `RespNode` is working  fine because I didnt get any error regarding that (meaning it is evaluating the assertion fine just not logging it.)

Comment: Actually I have a bug in my first example. I used `Eval.me()` accidentally instead of `Eval.xy()`. That could be the source of the bug (I'll fix the sample code now.

Comment: Continuing from before...
However, if you were smarter than me (not difficult some days) and picked up on the typo to begin with, then I suppose it might be objecting to the second parameter within the outer program rather than anything within the inner script string. Is it possible that you do not have the variable `log` defined in your outer scope?


Again, you might want to try switching to the more flexible `GroovyShell` and `Binding` approach.

Comment: ,thank you! It worked by using this as suggested `new GroovyShell(context).evaluate("assert ${RespNode}.toString() == '$aValue': log.info(\"info\")")` and it worked . The only thing I am trying to figure out now is why cant I use `${context.expand( '${#Project#assertValue}` in log.info. It works fine when I use a simpler statement like `log.info(\"info\")`. The error I am getting using former is `No signature of method: groovy.lang.Binding.expand()`.

Comment: That's my fault, @user1207289. I accidentally hijacked your preexisting `context` variable. If you change the name of my `context` variable to, say, `binding` then everything should be back to normal. I'll change the text of the sample code to reflect that.